# Strapi backend broken when enable custom middleware

Tags: javascript, strapi

I created a custom middleware that makes the api & admin unreachable when I enable it.

The middleware is pretty simple, it adds a request id to incoming request on the server:

```
const { createNamespace } = require('cls-hooked');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const loggerNamespace = createNamespace('logger');

module.exports = (strapi) => {
  return {
    initialize() {
      strapi.app.use((ctx, next) => {
        const reqId = ctx.request.get('X-Request-Id') || uuidv4();

        ctx.response.set('X-Request-Id', reqId);

        loggerNamespace.run(() => {
          loggerNamespace.set('requestId', reqId);

          next();
        });
      });
    },
  };
};
```

It's enable using the config file `./config/middleware.json`:

```
module.exports = {
  settings: {
    addRequestId: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  },
};
```

Then, when enabled, calling an API endpoint or trying to connect to admin results in `404` Not Found.

I use strapi `3.6.8` with node `14.18.1`.

Any idea why?

PS: I suspected `cls-hooked` to be the culprit but removing it for testing with an anemic middleware doesn't work either.

Comment: Could you try using `await next()` instead of just `next()`? OH, also, you might have to mark the callback function passed to `run` method as `async`.

Comment: I tried but didn't work as well

Comment: That was a good suggestion though, I found that I should await `run` using `runPromise`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Salvino put me on the right track suggesting that I should await the execution of `next`.

Digging in the code of `cls-hooked`, I found the method `runPromise` that is similar to `run` and returns a `Promise` that can be awaited. It solved the issue.

Fixed code:

```
const { createNamespace } = require('cls-hooked');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const loggerNamespace = createNamespace('logger');

module.exports = (strapi) => {
  return {
    initialize() {
      strapi.app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
        const reqId = ctx.request.get('X-Request-Id') || uuidv4();

        ctx.response.set('X-Request-Id', reqId);

        await loggerNamespace.runPromise(async () => {
          loggerNamespace.set('requestId', reqId);

          await next();
        });
      });
    },
  };
};
```